# How to use grpc-web in vue?

Tags: vue.js, grpc, grpc-web

I am trying use grpc-web client in my vue application as follows:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
const { Registration, _ } = require("./identity-service_pb.js");
const {
  IdentityServicePromiseClient
} = require("./identity-service_grpc_web_pb.js");

const identityService = new IdentityServicePromiseClient(
  "http://localhost:9000"
);


const req = new Registration();
req.setGender("male");
req.setInterestList(["A", "B", "C"]);

console.log(req);
console.log(identityService);

identityService.signUp(req, {}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

When the app gets compiled, the compiler complains:

```
error  in ./src/identity-service_pb.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/home/developer/js/identity-client/src/identity-service_pb.js
   27:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   28:50  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   30:15  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   31:20  error  'COMPILED' is not defined   no-undef
   36:3   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   48:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   51:15  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   52:20  error  'COMPILED' is not defined   no-undef
   57:3   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   65:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   82:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   83:10  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
   96:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  115:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  117:17  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  118:10  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  129:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  141:11  error  'value' is already defined  no-redeclare
  157:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  159:3   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  171:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  194:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  203:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  212:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  221:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  231:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  240:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  261:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  262:10  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  275:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  278:34  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  294:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  296:17  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  297:10  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  308:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  320:11  error  'value' is already defined  no-redeclare
  320:23  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  321:32  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  337:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  339:3   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  351:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  365:7   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  375:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  384:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  393:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  395:40  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  403:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  412:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  421:1   error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef
  426:29  error  'proto' is not defined      no-undef

✖ 50 problems (50 errors, 0 warnings)
```

As you can see, that the compiler complains about the auto generated file `identity-service_pb.js`.

The file structure looks as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Do I need an envoy proxy between vue app and golang app?

[image]

Or vue app can communicate directly with golang app? At the moment, I do not have envoy proxy between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need the `google-protobuf` npm package?

Comment: I've installed `google-protobuf` and `grpc-web` but did not configure the envoy proxy. Do I need the envoy proxy?

Comment: I have just updated my post. Could you please try to build a vue app with grcp-web and see if it is works

Comment: You definitely need the Envoy proxy. A normal gRPC Go app does not understand gRPC-Web

Answer (score 6):

I've been using react and gRPC with Go, I might be able to answer your questions:

- Yes, you do need an envoy-proxy between vue and your grpc server. Envoy will translate your HTTP/1.1 calls from the browser to HTTP2/ calls that are the ones gRPC handles
- To solve the compiler complaining about the auto generated file you can use `/*eslint-disable*/` at the beginning of the file and you'll bypass it
- To call gRPC methods you need to use the following format

```js
service.method(req, metadata, callback)
```

So in your case you could do something like:

```js
identityService.signUp(req, {}, async (err, response) => { 
    const data = await response
    console.log(data)
    console.log(err)
})
```